# Writing text to the log

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-12

Is it possible to write an arbitrary line of text to the log of a Cisco IOS 12.x device?

I should like to be able to put in markers when fetching configs via TFTP and I would like to be able to have log lines á la

```
 May 30 14:14:00.000: %CONFIG-REMARK: Halfway through the script! Now on to SomethingThatMightFail!
 May 30 14:14:05.000: %CONFIG-REMARK: SomethingThatMightFail didn't fail! Woo! Continuing!
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `send log` command:

```
switch#send log Halfway through the script!
```

gives my on a Catalyst 3750 with IOS 12.2

```
May 31 16:36:18: %SYS-2-LOGMSG: Message from 1(name): Halfway through the script!
```

and with IOS 15.0:

```
May 31 16:38:08: %SYS-7-USERLOG_DEBUG: Message from tty1(user id: name): Halfway through the script!
```

Comment: Interesting feature.

Comment: Tasty and spot on. Vielen Dank, Stefan.

Comment: Note: 7600 with 12.2(33) gives same line as your IOS 15 example :-)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for sending a test syslog from a Cisco device depends on software version; here are the command syntaxes I've seen, including, where available, the option for setting syslog severity:

Most Cisco platforms, if running IOS 12.2(58) and higher:

```
send log [severity] [text to send]
Eg:
send log
send log   This message will go to my syslog server.
send log 5 This message will go to my syslog server.
```

Most Cisco platforms, if running IOS 12.2(52) and lower:

```
send log [text to send]
Eg:
send log
send log   This message will go to my syslog server.
```

ASR1000 running IOS-XE 03.01.00, which is sourced from IOS 15.0(1):

```
send log [severity [text to send]]
Eg:
send log
send log 5 This message will go to my syslog server.
```

ASR1000 running other IOS-XE versions (including 02.04.03 from IOS 12.2(33), 03.04.04 from IOS 15.1(3), 03.14.00 from IOS 15.5(1)):

```
send log [severity] [text to send]
Eg:
send log
send log   This message will go to my syslog server.
send log 5 This message will go to my syslog server.
```

ASR9000 running IOS-XR 4.2.1 and higher:

```
log <text to send>
Eg:
log This message will go to my syslog server.
```

WS-C6513 running IOS 12.2(18): No equivalent command; you need to use another method to generate a syslog message.  For example, the following should generate 5 syslogs (interface up, line protocol up, interface down, line protocol down, and configuration changed), depending on your logging settings.  Leave out the 2 interface commands to generate just the one generic configuration-changed syslog.

```
config t
interface loopback601
no interface loopback601
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using TCL EEM you can use [action_syslog](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/netmgmt/configuration/guide/nm_eem_policy_tcl.html#wp1208703).

Comment: Nope, no TCL anywhere in our network. Shell scripts using clogin.